# Tab Bar like WhatsApp

Tags: blackberry, user-interface, java-me, tabs, tabbar

How do I create a tab bar like WhatsApp on BlackBerry in my BlackBerry app? I want that feature in BlackBerry OS 7.0. I have used managers -- HorizontalFieldManager and VerticalFieldManager -- to achieve it. But it doesn't look as attractive as WhatsApp. Can FieldTabController help me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to look attractive if you are just making tweaks to the code, and then seeing what that looks like. You need to start with a design you find attractive.  Once you have that goal put together as an image, you start writing code to make the UI look like the design image.

The WhatsApp tab bar is not a straightforward combination of built-in UI managers from RIM. It has a fair amount of customization - each tab has three visual states, and there is a tooltip that follows the focus, as well as a context tab on the right that changes depending on the currently selected main tab.  This means there are several interacting UI components here, not just a single magic manager.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you will probably want to start building your own custom `Field` objects.

Basically, subclass the `Field` class (or one of the other subclasses), and learn to love the [paint(..) method](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#paint%28net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics%29) and the [Graphics API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html).